# How to handle Google play services errors inside a Service

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-dialogfragment

I have checked Google play service apk on device using following code.

1. [In Android Training section](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#CheckServices) they created `ErrorDialogFragment` class separately and show the dialog,but in my code I used `GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment` method directly.Why they created a seperate dialog Fragment and setDialog with `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog` method?
2. [In Android Training section](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#CheckServices) they checked play services inside an Activity.But How do I check inside a `service` which connects `LocationClient` to fetch location.If I check inside a service how to handle Errors,because no activity is visible,so not able to display dialog fragment?

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
>
>         private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000 ;
>         private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
>         private LocationClient mLocationClient;
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>             mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onResume() {
>             super.onResume();
>
>             if(playServicesConnected()){
>                 mLocationClient.connect();
>             }
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onPause() {
>             super.onPause();
>             if(playServicesConnected()) {
>                 mLocationClient.disconnect();
>             }
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>             switch (requestCode){
>                 case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:
>                     switch(resultCode){
>                         case Activity.RESULT_OK:
>                             Log.d(TAG,"Play Connected");
>                             Log.d(TAG,"Resolution Available");
>                             break;
>                         default:
>                             Log.d(TAG,"Play Disconnected");
>                             Log.d(TAG,"No Resolution");
>                             break;
>                     }
>                 default:
>                     Log.d(TAG,"Some other request from Play Services");
>                     break;
>             }
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Check Google Play Service apk available on device
>          * If not exist return error dialog to install or update google play service apk
>          * @return boolean It returns true if play service apk available,otherwise return false.
>          */
>         private boolean playServicesConnected()
>         {
>             int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
>
>             if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode){
>
>                 Log.d(TAG,"Google Play Services Available");
>                 return true;
>
>             }else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
>
>                 Log.d(TAG,"Google Play Services Not Available");
>                 GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment(resultCode,this,CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
>                 return false;
>             }else {
>                 Log.d(TAG,"This device not supported");
>                 //Toast.makeText(this,"This device not supported ->"+ConnectionResult,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                 GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment(resultCode,this,CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
>
>                 return false;
>             }
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
>             Log.d(TAG,"Location client Connected");
>             Toast.makeText(this,"Location client Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>             Location mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
>             Log.d(TAG,"mCurrentLocation ->" + mCurrentLocation);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onDisconnected() {
>             Log.d(TAG,"Location client DisConnected");
>             Toast.makeText(this,"Location client DisConnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
>             Log.d(TAG,"Location client connection failed");
>             Toast.makeText(this,"Location client connection failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>             if(connectionResult.hasResolution()){
>                 Log.d(TAG, "Location client connection failed -> Resolution available");
>                 try {
>                     connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
>                 } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
>                     Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
>                     Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                 }
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 Log.d(TAG, "Location client connection failed -> No Resolution");
>                 GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment(connectionResult.getErrorCode(),this,CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: have u resolved issue can u pls share how u have resolved ?

Comment: You can send a message (either via Square's Otto or LocalBroadcastManager), then in receiver side (your activity or fragment...) register a listener for the message.